# Navigating to a new screen using a button in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am new to swiftUI and am having difficulty moving from one UIViewController to another UIViewController. Rights now I have a state called navigate and a button, but I am not sure how to move this screen to a new screen. Here is the code.

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var navigate = false

    var body: some View {

    Button(action: { self.navigate.toggle() }) {
        Text("Get Involved")
            .font(.custom("PlayfairDisplay-Regular", size: 18))
            .foregroundColor(Color("Dark Text"))
       }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the blank screen.

```
import SwiftUI

struct GoalIdeasView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
}
```

How would I go about navigating to the second screen from the ContentView Controller once the button is pressed?

Comment: You should look at this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/216/complete-guide-to-navigationview-in-swiftui

Answer (score 0):

There is a view called `Navigation` that act like `UINavigationViewController`. Then you can use a `NavigationLink` to navigate between `view`s. So it would be like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Get Involved", destination: GoalIdeasView())
                .font(.custom("PlayfairDisplay-Regular", size: 18))
        }
    }
}
```